# Object created from layout xml file is null

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two classes that extend the activity class. Each class has it's own layout class, `main.xml` and `compose.xml`.

In my main activity I try to access a layout element that is in `compose.xml`. So:

```
EditText smsBody = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smsBody);
```

But smsBody is `null`. Why? How can I access it?

Comment: Did you try cleaning up the project ?

Comment: To be frank , this has also happened to me a few times.If you google findViewById returning null, you will get many posts, most of times it worked using cleanup and for me too.Can you postthe XML and Code here.I HOPE YOU HAVE DONE setContentView() before doing findViewById for the EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the content view in the `onCreate()` method?

Like in this example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did set the content view

Comment: When you try to access a child of `compose.xml`, you need to adjust this line: `setContentView(R.layout.compose);`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your main activity has a `main.xml` layout. Your compose activity has a `compose.xml` layout. Assuming your "smsBody" `EditText` is in the `compose.xml` layout, then this will be only accesible in your compose activity, since that widget doesn't exist in your `main.xml` layout.

Answer (score 1):

when main activity have layout main.xml, how you can expect that you can access component of compose.xml ?? you suppose to play with view inside layout you set using setContentView() .

in exceptional cases we need to use other layouts as well , so you can use `LayoutInflater` for this